# How to use lambda statements to initialize UIPropertyMetaData in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I know this is basic, but I'm not getting it. I simply wish to initialize the dependency property `Dashes` as a double collection using the lambda operator.

What is the proper syntax?

Thank you.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DashesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Dashes", typeof(DoubleCollection), typeof(CustomTextBlock),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(
             () =>
            {
                DoubleCollection d = new DoubleCollection();
                d.Add(4);
                d.Add(4);
                return d;
            }
     ));
```

Comment: @RohitVats, DoubleCollection *is* a type...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should *avoid passing default value for reference types in DP metadata* because that will be shared across all instances of containing class which you didn't intend to.

Say, you declared two instances of CustomTextBlock, then both instances will refer to same list and any modification in list will be transparent to both instances. Unless you explicitly setting it from constructor or somewhere else.

[**Be careful with default values of DP for reference types.**](http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2010/02/11/be-careful-with-default-values-of-dependency-properties-if-youre-using-reference-types/)

---

Anyhow, if you still want it, here how it is done:

```
new UIPropertyMetadata(new DoubleCollection() { 4, 5 })
```

---

**UPDATE**:

If you pass default value in metadata, then DoubleCollection's gets freezed automatically i.e. you can't add/delete from the collection in that case.

```
var dashesCollection = new CustomTextBlock().Dashes.Add(5); // Will throw exception.
```

However, if you set it explicitly from constructor, it's not marked as Frozen and items can be added/deleted from the collection.

```
var dashesCollection = new CustomTextBlock().Dashes.Add(5); // Works fine.
```

So, ***essence is to set the value in constructor and not in metadata of DP identifier***.

Comment: I think the OP is aware of the issue with reference type DPs, otherwise he wouldn't be trying to use a lambda instead of passing the value directly.

Comment: @RohitVats  Thanks. Why wouldn't I intend to have a constant shared among all instances?

Comment: @AlanWayne, because it's not really a constant! The `DoubleCollection` class is mutable: you can add, remove or replace items in it. And the changes will be shared by all instances of `CustomTextBlock`, which is probably not what you want...

Comment: @AlanWayne - For values types it does make sense. But for reference types, it doesn't. Say you have two instances of CustomTextBlock and you want to add 5 in Dashes collection in first instance but 5 will be shown added in second instance as well because internally they are referring to same instance of collection.

Comment: @AlanWayne, actually, there is a way to make it safe, by `Freeze`ing  the collection. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Clemens - Right, I also recommend against doing this.

Comment: @Thomas - I just tested that if default value is passed in the metadata, it's by default frozen and no need to call Freeze() on it explicitly.

Comment: @RohitVats, ah, that's very good to know! I wasn't sure and I was to lazy to check ;)

Comment: @RohitVats this is all quite nice, but is this behaviour documented anywhere, or probably just an implementation detail of the current WPF version? I'd still strongly suggest to set the default value in the constructor.

Comment: @Clemens - Unfortunately, I did tried to find some documentation for it but couldn't find any. And yeah me too in favour of setting value in constructor.

Comment: @Clemens, it might be an undocumented implementation detail, but I think it's unlikely to change; it makes sense that default DP values should be frozen, and I don't see any reason why they should change it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that's not possible. You can only provide a value, not a value factory. The workaround is to initialize the property in the constructor:

```
public CustomTextBlock()
{
    Dashes = new DoubleCollection {4, 4};
}
```

---

Actually, I just realized that since `DoubleCollection` is `Freezable`, passing an instance of `DoubleCollection` as the default value (as suggested by Rohit Vats) could work<strike>, as long as you call `Freeze` on it. You could do it like this:</strike>

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DashesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Dashes", typeof(DoubleCollection), typeof(CustomTextBlock),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(CreateDefaultDashes()));

private static DoubleCollection CreateDefaultDashes()
{
    var dashes = new DoubleCollection { 4, 4 };
    dashes.Freeze();
    return dashes;
}
```

This makes the collection immutable, which means it can safely be shared among instances of `CustomTextBlock`.

OK, actually it seems that the default value is automatically frozen, so you don't need to do anything special. It is safe as a default value, because it becomes immutable when it's frozen.

Comment: So...don't use UIPropertyMetadata at all?

Comment: @AlanWayne, no, you don't need it in this case, since you can't provide a sensible default value.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to SO. I would like to mark this as an answer too, but I can't seem to mark more then one answer.

Comment: @AlanWayne, no, there can be only one... you can always upvote if you like that answer.